# "users" command not found in docker container built from alpine

Tags: linux, docker, alpine-linux

"users" command is not found in docker container built from alpine:latest. 
How can I install users command?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from [this page](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=users&path=&name=coreutils&branch=&repo=&arch=) the users command is provided by the coreutils package. To install it simply run:

```
apk update && apk add coreutils
```